# How to quickly rename a bunch of files in the folder

Tags: unix, rename, batch-rename

I have a bunch of files that are named 'something_12345.doc' (any 5-digit number, not necessarily 12345). I need to rename them all to just 'something.doc'. This is a Unix filesystem, and I suspect there's a way to do this with just one command... Can any Unix regular expressions guru help?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll be left with one file, basically, you are deleting N-1 files and copying the Nth file to `something.doc` -- Is this what you want?

Comment: -1 because asked *often*. You should search on SO first.

Answer (score 3):

@OP, the shell has already expanding your pattern for you, there in your mv statement, you don't have to specify  the pattern for 5 digits again.

```
for file in *_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].doc
do
  echo mv "$file" "${file%_*}.doc"
done
```

Comment: Thanks ghostdog74 & everyone else!

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked a **lot** of times on SO:

- [bash script to rename all files in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956144/bash-script-to-rename-all-files-in-a-directory)
- [bash Linux - Massive folder rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051204/bash-linux-massive-folder-rename)
- [How to do a mass rename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417916/how-to-do-a-mass-rename)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137/replacing-one-string-in-a-bunch-of-file-names-with-another

My personal preference goes to [mmv](http://linux.maruhn.com/sec/mmv.html). But see "[Mass Rename/copy/link Tools](http://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/mass-rename.html)".

Answer (score 2):

`rename 's/_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]//' *.doc`

Comment: I'm on FreeBSD, so this doesn't work.. 

bash: /usr/local/bin/rename: Argument list too long

I can't figure out how to set variables for rename

Comment: Figured it out.

for i in [A-Za-z]*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].doc; do mv "$i" "${i/_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}"; done

Answer (score 1):

use sed

```
ls *.doc | sed 's:\([^0-9_]\)[0-9_][0-9_]*\.doc:$(mv & \1.doc)' | /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `rename` takes perl style regular expressions. Do a [`man rename`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rename).

Comment: Not always. On RH systems it does a simple string replacement.

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD, you might be interested in the sysutils/renameutils port. The command `qmv` opens your $EDITOR and allows you to specify all file renames in a reasonably comfortable environment. I personally prefer the `qmv -fdo` (single column) format.